# ASP.NET Core Web Application cannot find cookie value. What am i missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies

I have created a simple web cookie from my ASP.NET web form application. I am trying to retrieve this cookie from a separate.NET Core web application. Whenever I try to do this, the .NET Core application keeps returning null values for the cookie.

This is how the cookie is created in the ASP.NET web form application:

```
 protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie Abc = new HttpCookie("Abc");
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            //Abc Set the cookie value.
            Abc.Value = txt1.Text;
            // Set the cookie expiration date.
            Abc.Expires = now.AddMinutes(1);

            // Add the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(Abc);

       }
```

This is how I am trying to read this "Abc" cookie from the .NET Core application:

```
public void OnGet()
        {

         if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Abc"] != null)
            {
                Message = "ya";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "no";
            }
        }
```

Here is the Startup.cs details for the ASP.NET CORE app:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
          //  services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // No consent check needed here
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

I am able to find the cookie in the browser as expected when I run the ASP .NET Core app:

[image]

I have spent quite a few hours researching this but was not successful. Any ideas as to why I cannot read the cookie from the .Net Core app? I greatly appreciate any feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using?

Comment: Hi @EdneyHolder, i am using netcoreapp3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web apps are hosted in sub-domains of the same domain (e.g. app1.example.com and app2.example.com), then you can easily read cookies between sub-domains by setting the "Domain" property of the HttpCookie object to .example.com

```
HttpCookie Abc = new HttpCookie("Abc");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Abc.Domain = ".example.com";
//Abc Set the cookie value.
Abc.Value = txt1.Text;
// Set the cookie expiration date.
Abc.Expires = now.AddMinutes(1);

// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(Abc);
```

Comment: Hi @Anuraj, I am running both applications through visual studio - so they are both running on localhost.

Comment: It should be identical - if you use different port - it is a different domain

Comment: Ahhh that could be it. Thanks Anuraj!